# Laravel mute Observer event in chaining relationship create method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9, observers

I have a question on how to mute the observer's method based on the parameters I pass. I have a parameter of `link_social` and if it is set to false I wanted the observer to not trigger the `created()` function.

```
       $role = $request->role == 'creator' ? 'creator' : 'sponsor';

        if($request->link_social == true){
            $user = Auth::user()->$role()->create([
                'name' => $request->safe()->name,
                'about' => $request->safe()->about,
                'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
            ]);
        } else{
            $user = Auth::user()->$role()->create([
                'name' => $request->safe()->name,
                'about' => $request->safe()->about,
                'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
            ])->saveQuietly();
        }
```

The `User` model has a relationship method `creator` and the observer is from that model named `CreatorObserver`

but I got this
`"message": "Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Creator::saveQuitely()"`

error when saving (edited) and still it triggers the `created()` event in the creator observer which is saving a record in another table.

I am trying to do someting like `$user->role->create()->saveQuitely()`

CreatorObserver

```
class CreatorObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the Creator "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\Creator  $creator
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Creator $creator)
    {
        if ($creator->user->social_identifier['platform'] === PlatformType::Google->value) {
            $youtube = new YoutubeService($creator->user->social_identifier);
            SocialPlatform::createFor($creator, $youtube);
        }
    }
}
```

User model

```
    public function sponsor()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Sponsor::class);
    }

    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Creator::class);
    }
```

Creator Model

```
class Creator extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function socialPlatforms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SocialPlatform::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the relations definitions and the observer registration

Comment: try to grap your creation code with Creator::withoutEvents, i Know this is not the best way to do it but just to get a point where we can move forward

Comment: what do you mean by that? I kinda confused. sorry.

Comment: where you want to saveQuitly do this $user = Creator::withoutEvents(function () use ($role, $request, $accountPlan) {
            return Auth::user()->$role()->create([
                'name' => $request->safe()->name,
                'about' => $request->safe()->about,
                'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
            ]);
        });

Comment: Instead of `saveQuietly` use `createQuietly` (use that where you put `create(...)->saveQuietly() = createQuietly(...)`

Comment: i got this `Call to undefined method App\\Models\\Creator::createQuietly()` @matiaslauriti

Comment: your solution works @Znar but is this the right way?

Comment: as @matiaslauriti mentioned try it like this $user = Auth::user()->$role()->createQuitely([
            'name' => $request->safe()->name,
            'about' => $request->safe()->about,
            'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
        ]); it should work

Comment: tried that one but i got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Relations\\HasOne::createQuitely()` @Znar

Comment: sorry looks like I missed typed the function name it should be createQuietly not createQuitely

Comment: Yeah both of your solution works Znar & matiaslauriti. Can you post your answers and some explanations so that when someone encounter this problem have an idea. Thanks

Comment: but its for `creator` model only @Znar how about if the parameter is a `sponsor`?

Comment: createQuietly will work fine for both and if you want to go with the first approach you can do $user = Model::withoutEvents(your code here), i changed the Creator::withoutEvenets to be Model::withoutEvents and this is excatly what laravel do if you check the createQuietly function in the framework

Comment: I would go with createQuietly as it is simple, clear and more readable for me when cheching the code again, both works fine. and the problem was to not chain the saveQuietly after create as create will fire the creation event

Comment: yeah and also `createQuietly` seems kinda new https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/45783/commits. Can you post your answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

saveQuietly/ createQuietly shouldn't be chained after create as the create function will dispatch the creation events which is handled by the observer created function.
to prevent the model from dispatching the event it can be done in one of two ways:
using createQuietly

```
$user = Auth::user()->$role()->createQuietly([
        'name' => $request->safe()->name,
        'about' => $request->safe()->about,
        'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
    ]);
```

or use the model withoutEvents function

```
$user = Model::withoutEvents(function () use ($request, $role, $accountPlan) {
        return Auth::user()->$role()->create([
            'name' => $request->safe()->name,
            'about' => $request->safe()->about,
            'account_plan_id' => $accountPlan->id,
        ]);
    });
```

base Model was used as the created model can be Creator or Sponsor if the model class is known we can replace Model::withoutEvents to be YourModelName::withoutEvents